# Why isn't my link being associated with the correct action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', store_product_path(@store, @product), :method => 'delete', :confirm => 'This cannot be undone. Are you sure?', :class => 'btn'  %>
```

And here's what it looks like as compiled HTML:

```
<a href="/stores/237/products/193-no-image" class="btn" data-confirm="This cannot be undone. Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

All it's supposed to do is delete the product, but it's now being associated with the `products#show` action and not the `products#destroy` action like it should be.

When I run `rake routes` here's what it returns for products:

```
                      products GET    /products(.:format)                                                   products#index
                               POST   /products(.:format)                                                   products#create
                   new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)                                               products#new
                  edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)                                          products#edit
                       product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                                               products#show
                               PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                                               products#update
                               DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                                               products#destroy
```

So, I'm not sure what's wrong with the link. Is there a more verbose way to write the link that may work for me? Thanks

Comment: Did my answer resolve your query? I have also answered your other question too. Please try the solution and let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you don't have nested resources "products" within "stores". As per the rake routes,
you have defined routes for products as

`resources :products`

So, your link should look like

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', product_path(@product), :method => 'delete', :confirm => 'This cannot be undone. Are you sure?', :class => 'btn'  %>
```

---

Assuming that you have a resource called `stores` then in that case in order to achieve route like `/stores/237/products/193-no-image` for destroy action:

Routes should be defined as:

```
resources :stores do
  resources :products
end
```

And your current link would work as it is. **No need to change anything as long as the routes are defined as suggested above**.